# How to get a notification ( by an email ) of mainframe job completion

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am looking for your help , actually everyday i have to monitor my TWSZ/OPC jobs on system and its really boring to check .. 
I would like to know if is there any way to get a notification once our OPC jobs whether are completed or no

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked whether it is possible just using TWS/OPC? Remember, email has no guaranteed delivery time. You can certainly send email from a batch step/JOB, or do you have constrains on changing or adding anything? At the moment your question is "I'd like to do something, using almost anything, I have Product X". You need to ask a question which is on-topic. See the help, and the help centre.

Answer (score 2):

One very easy way to approach this is to get the freely available XMITIP package and add an end of job email step to let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

You can find XMITIP in [www.cbttape.org](http://www.cbttape.org) file 314 and at https://github.com/lbdyck/xmitip